# The node positions in chain changed unexpectedly

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, foreach, tikz-chains

As shown below, the node positions have been changed when using `chain`. How to fix it?

[image: node-position-in-chain]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain = arc]
  % with chain
  \foreach \p in {{0,0}, {1,1}, {2,1.5}, {3,2}, {4, 1.5}, {5,1}, {6,0}} {
    \node [draw, circle, minimum size = 6pt, on chain, join] at (\p) {};
  }
  % without chain
  \begin{scope}[yshift = -3cm]
    \foreach \p in {{0,0}, {1,1}, {2,1.5}, {3,2}, {4, 1.5}, {5,1}, {6,0}} {
      \node [draw, circle, minimum size = 6pt] at (\p) {};
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify no direction, i.e. a placement rule, after the name of your chain in the form of `going direction` or `placed direction`, the chain uses the [`chain default direction`](https://tikz.dev/library-chains#tikz/chain:default:direction) which is `going right`.

This means, for every node (except the first), the option `right = of \tikzchainprevious` (of the `positioning` library) will be executed.
This is essentially:

1. `at = (\tikzchainprevious.east)`,
2. `xshift = node distance` and
3. `anchor = west`.

Since you use `at (\p)`, the first setting is overwritten but both the transformation and the anchor remain.

Since the default `node distance` is 1cm every node after the first will be shifted to the right by that distance and will placed there with its west anchor.

This can be seen very good when a grid is added to the diagram since the nodes now touch the vertical lines with the left side.

---

If you want to use the `chains` library without the automatic placement just use nothing as the `direction`.

Alternatively, you could also use `=` for the direction but both the `=` as well as the nothing needs special care because of how PGFKeys works.

You will need

- `start chain = {arc going }`,
- `start chain = arc going {}`,
- `start chain = arc going {=}` or
- `start chain = {arc going =}`.

If the direction contains a `=` then it will just be executed when the node is placed directly (without it getting turned into `= of \tikzchainprevious`).

But both cases will be ignored silently by PGFKeys because it sees an empty key name.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every on chain/.append style=join,
  nodes={draw, circle, minimum size = 6pt}
]
\draw[help lines] (-.25,-6.25) grid (7.5,2.5);
\scoped[start chain = arc, nodes=on chain]
  \foreach \p in {{0,0}, {1,1}, {2,1.5}, {3,2}, {4, 1.5}, {5,1}, {6,0}}
    \node at (\p) {};

\scoped[start chain = arc going {}, nodes = on chain, yshift=-3cm]
  \foreach \p in {{0,0}, {1,1}, {2,1.5}, {3,2}, {4, 1.5}, {5,1}, {6,0}}
    \node at (\p) {};

\scoped[yshift=-6cm]
  \foreach \p in {{0,0}, {1,1}, {2,1.5}, {3,2}, {4, 1.5}, {5,1}, {6,0}}
    \node at (\p) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Chains come with a predefined node distance. If you set it to 0, or even better, to an appropriate negative distance, you avoid the shift. What is this appropriate distance? You give the nodes a minimum size of `6pt`, but you also go into a 45 degree direction. This suggests that this distance is `6pt/sqrt(2)` plus some outer sep. At least numerically this seems to fit rather well.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, chains,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain = arc]
  % with chain, no distance modified
  \foreach \p [count=\X] in {{0,0}, {1,1}, {2,1.5}, {3,2}, {4, 1.5}, {5,1}, {6,0}} {
    \node [draw, circle, minimum size = 6pt, on chain, join] at (\p) (u-\X) { };
      \draw let \p1=(u-\X) in node[anchor=south] at (u-\X.north) {\x1}
       node[anchor=north] at (u-\X.south) {\y1};
  }
  % chain, node distance set to 0
  \begin{scope}[yshift =-3cm,start chain=arc2,node distance=0pt]
  \foreach \p [count=\X] in {{0,0}, {1,1}, {2,1.5}, {3,2}, {4, 1.5}, {5,1}, {6,0}} {
    \node [draw, circle, minimum size = 6pt, on chain, join] at (\p) (m-\X) { };
      \draw let \p1=(m-\X) in node[anchor=south] at (m-\X.north) {\x1}
       node[anchor=north] at (m-\X.south) {\y1};
  }
  \end{scope}
  % chain, 
  \begin{scope}[yshift =-6cm,start chain=arc3,node distance={-(6/sqrt(2))*1pt
  -2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}-\pgflinewidth/sqrt(2)}]
  \foreach \p [count=\X] in {{0,0}, {1,1}, {2,1.5}, {3,2}, {4, 1.5}, {5,1}, {6,0}} {
    \node [draw, circle, minimum size = 6pt, on chain, join] at (\p) (n-\X) { };
      \draw let \p1=(n-\X) in node[anchor=south] at (n-\X.north) {\x1}
       node[anchor=north] at (n-\X.south) {\y1};
  }
  \end{scope}
  % without chain
  \begin{scope}[yshift = -9cm]
    \foreach \p [count=\X] in {{0,0}, {1,1}, {2,1.5}, {3,2}, {4, 1.5}, {5,1}, {6,0}} {
      \node [draw, circle, minimum size = 6pt] at (\p)
      (l-\X) {};
      \draw let \p1=(l-\X) in node[anchor=south] at (l-\X.north) {\x1}
       node[anchor=north] at (l-\X.south) {\y1};
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Whether this is the full explanation, I don't know.

Comment: Of course, chains are made to avoid specifying their location explicitly, so it is not too surprising that the explicit placement fails.