# Time arrow with "current position" evolving with overlay number

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm showing slides where I show a time evolution by going through snapshots. Each snapshot corresponds to a specific time.

I'd like to show a time arrow (vertically on the side) with bullets corresponding to each of the time points (unequally spaced). On each overlay, one of these bullets is solid filled and the current time is specified, whereas the other bullets are open (empty circles).

I think I can do the unaminated version quite easily with `tikz`, but I am not sure how to adjust the style of elements and presence of node text depending on overlay number.

Here's a MWE for a static timearrow:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\axscale{-0.02}
  \def\thex{0}
  \def\they{0}
  \def\prevy{0}
  \def\times{{-5,2, 12, 22, 32, 44, 76, 116, 182, 300,307}}
  \def\maxt{9}
  \foreach \it in {1,...,\maxt} {
        \pgfmathparse{\axscale*\times[\it-1]}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\prevy}{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathparse{\axscale*\times[\it]}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\they}{\pgfmathresult}
        \draw[-{Circle[open]}] (\thex,\prevy) -- (\thex,\they);
        \node[right,anchor=west] at (\thex,\they) {
            $t=\pgfmathparse{\times[\it]}
            \pgfmathprintnumber[    % Print the result
                fixed,
                fixed zerofill,
                precision=0,
                assume math mode=true
            ]{\pgfmathresult}
            $};
  }
  \pgfmathparse{\axscale*\times[\maxt]}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\prevy}{\pgfmathresult}
  \pgfmathparse{\axscale*\times[\maxt+1]}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\they}{\pgfmathresult}
  \draw[->] (\thex,\prevy) -- (\thex,\they);
  %\draw(\thex,\prevy) -- (\thex+5,\they);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So the elements to animate are `Circle[open]` and whether to display the `t=...` label.

Comment: If you show us the unanimated version with tikz, I'm sure we can then help you to do the animation

Comment: You can just do `\pgfmathsetmacro\mymacro{<my formula>}`. `\pgfmathsetmacro` is also doing `\pgfmathparse` *and* stores the result in `\mymacro`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you got your answer, i.e. use layers *with* TikZ, and both answers show how one can do this.

I want to show a different way to draw this timeline by using a few goodies, TikZ has to offer, mainly **the `/tikz/y` key** where you can change the length and the direction of the *y* axis of the *xyz* coordinate system (the one without units).

Instead of using `\axscale` you can just set `y` to `-0.02cm` (where the default is 1cm) and TikZ multiplicates your value to transform it into the *canvas* coordinate system (the one with units where *y* still points upwards).

Then, there's the **`chains` library**  which I'm actually only using to join nodes by not having it [go anywhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/678058/16595).
For this I setup a start point that is `1mm` above *t* = 0 and also add a last point that is always 1.4mm below the last *t*. (If you need the upper start of the line to be a fixed distance above the first *t* an adjustment is necessary here.) The last one is also joined by `->` so that we get an the actual arrow tip.

Speaking of arrow tips, while the **`Circle` tip** seems like a nice thing, they only touch the specified coordinate instead of lying centered on them. This can be [fixed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11871/16595), though I'd just use circle nodes here.

For making the diagram beamer aware, I'm stealing the `<.>` syntax from [Sam Carter's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/678167) to have the **`label`** show up at the same time as the filling of the node.
Since I'm using a circle node as reference instead of an arrow tip, the node will line up much better in my opinion.

We could also add the `label` to the `fill`, i.e.

```
alt=<+>{fill, label={$t = \t$}}{}
```

though this will make the picture jump around unless the label wouldn't contribute to the bounding box anymore.
Since the `visible on` solution from `overlay-beamer-styles` will leave hidden text on the frame (which can get selected and copied), I'm using beamer's own `\uncover` to hide the text.

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item First.
\item Second.
\end{itemize}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  y=-.02cm, thick, label position=right, start chain = going {},
  dot/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+1.3mm}]
\coordinate[on chain]() at (0, 1mm); % a start (for the line)
\foreach \t in {2, 12, 22, 32, 44, 76, 116, 182, 300}
  \node[dot, on chain, join, alt=<+>{fill},
    label/.expanded={$\uncover<.>{t = \t}$}, % no hidden text in output
%    label={[visible on=<.>]$t = \t$},       % hidden text in output
  ] at (0, \t) {};
% and an end that is below the last dot
\coordinate[on chain, join=by ->]() at ([yshift=-1.4mm] chain-end.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

#### Output (click for full version)

[image: Thumbnail to full file]

Comment: So much more compact than my code! I was quite sure it was possible, but since there were requests to close my question before I offered my clumsy own work, I felt I had to go thru that and then bias the answer towards just a patch of my code.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of the fact that tikz commands, like `\draw`, are overlay aware:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\axscale{-0.02}
  \def\thex{0}
  \def\they{0}
  \def\prevy{0}
  \def\times{{-5,2, 12, 22, 32, 44, 76, 116, 182, 300,307}}
  \def\maxt{9}
  \foreach \it in {1,...,\maxt} {
        \pgfmathparse{\axscale*\times[\it-1]}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\prevy}{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathparse{\axscale*\times[\it]}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\they}{\pgfmathresult}
        \draw[-{Circle[open]}] (\thex,\prevy) -- (\thex,\they);
        \draw<+(2)>[-{Circle}] (\thex,\prevy) -- (\thex,\they);
        \node<.(2)>[right,anchor=west] at (\thex,\they) {
            $t=\pgfmathparse{\times[\it]}
            \pgfmathprintnumber[    % Print the result
                fixed,
                fixed zerofill,
                precision=0,
                assume math mode=true
            ]{\pgfmathresult}
            $};
  }
  \pgfmathparse{\axscale*\times[\maxt]}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\prevy}{\pgfmathresult}
  \pgfmathparse{\axscale*\times[\maxt+1]}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\they}{\pgfmathresult}
  \draw[->] (\thex,\prevy) -- (\thex,\they);
  %\draw(\thex,\prevy) -- (\thex+5,\they);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know of `<+>`. Since there are 2 overlays before I start using that time line, I have found that `<+(2)>` was the appropriate choice, and I've actually grouped the `draw` and `node` commands in an `only<+(2)>` one since I want the times too to show only on the corresponding slide.

Comment: @JoceNoToPutinsWarInUkraine You can use `\node<.(2)>`  to show the node only on the same overlay as the filled circle. However if you are only showing the times one at a time, I would use the `visible on` option from the `overlay-beamer-styles` library @Jasper Habicht uses in his answer. This avoid the slight height difference from showing the first/last node which causes a bit of jump between the slides.

Comment: +1. I have actually lengthened the arrow above first and below last time point for other reasons, so I don't have this jump. But that's usefule to note, as well as the `<.>` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Using the great `overlay-beamer-styles` library, you can do:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\axscale{-0.02}
  \def\thex{0}
  \def\they{0}
  \def\prevy{0}
  \def\times{{-5, 2, 12, 22, 32, 44, 76, 116, 182, 300, 307}}
  \def\maxt{9}
  \foreach \it in {1,...,\maxt} {
        \pgfmathparse{\axscale*\times[\it-1]}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\prevy}{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathparse{\axscale*\times[\it]}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\they}{\pgfmathresult}
        \draw[alt={<\it>{-{Circle[]}}{-{Circle[open]}}}] (\thex,\prevy) -- (\thex,\they);
        \node[right,anchor=west] at (\thex,\they) {
            $t=\pgfmathparse{\times[\it]}
            \pgfmathprintnumber[    % Print the result
                fixed,
                fixed zerofill,
                precision=0,
                assume math mode=true
            ]{\pgfmathresult}
            $};
  \pgfmathparse{\axscale*\times[\maxt]}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\prevy}{\pgfmathresult}
  \pgfmathparse{\axscale*\times[\maxt+1]}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\they}{\pgfmathresult}
  \draw[->] (\thex,\prevy) -- (\thex,\they);
  }
  %\draw(\thex,\prevy) -- (\thex+5,\they);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can replace `alt={<\it>{-{Circle[]}}{-{Circle[open]}}}` with `alt={<\it->{-{Circle[]}}{-{Circle[open]}}}` (that is, add a `-` after `\it`) if you want to keep the previous dots filled.